# Replacing NaN with other value (mean) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan

I have matrix `A` such as:

```
A = [1  2  3 NaN;
     1 NaN 2 NaN;
     NaN 2 3 4]
```

I would like to replace every `NaN` in `A` with a predefined value such as my columns vector `B`:

```
B = [2; 1.5; 3]
```

So for the second row, I'd like to obtain a new matrix, where every NaN in this particular row is replaced by `1.5`. It would be `2` in the first row and `3` in the third row.

Is there a better way to do so other than looping through the entire matrix? I used a `for` loop with the `if` and `else` conditions. However, this solution does not execute very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
A = [
    1 2 3 NaN;
    1 NaN 2 NaN;
    NaN 2 3 4
];

B = [2; 1.5; 3];
B = repmat(B,1,size(A,2));

idx = isnan(A);
A(idx) = B(idx);
```

Since you are speaking about a row mean in the title of your question, I suppose that the vector `B` must not be manually defined, but it should rather be calculated from your `A` matrix. So:

```
A = [
    1 2 3 NaN;
    1 NaN 2 NaN;
    NaN 2 3 4
];

B = repmat(nanmean(A,2),1,size(A,2));

idx = isnan(A);
A(idx) = B(idx);
```

Comment: `nanmean` requires Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) (introduced in R2015a). The trick is to repeat the entries of `B` according to the number of times `NaN` appears in each row of `A`.

```
req = A.';
req(isnan(req)) = repelem(B, sum(isnan(req)));
req = req.';
```

If you also want to calculate `B`, use `mean` with the [`'omitnan'` flag](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html#buql3m_) (introduced in R2015a) i.e.

```
B = mean(A,2,'omitnan');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it likes the following:

```
is_NaN = find(isnan(A) > 0); % find index of NaNs
[I,~] = ind2sub(size(A), is_NaN); %transform from linear index to sub index
A(is_NaN) = B(I); % replace all using the row number of each found index
```

Comment: You can combine the first two steps into `[I,~] = find(isnan(A));`